# Null and IN() provides unexpected results

Tags: sql, null, matching

This seems so basic, I'm flabbergasted for lack of a better word. I have two tables, let's call them `albums` and `artists`

```
CREATE TABLE `albums` (
  `album_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `artist_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`album_id`)
)
CREATE TABLE `artists` (
  `artist_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`artist_id`)
)
```

There are a few hundred thousand reconds in each table. Some of the album rows have a null `artist_id`, this is expected.

However, when I perform the following query to find artists without albums:

`SELECT * FROM artists WHERE artist_id NOT IN (SELECT artist_id FROM albums)`

... the query returns zero results. I know that this is not true. So I tried this one:

`SELECT * FROM artists WHERE artist_id NOT IN (SELECT artist_id FROM albums WHERE artist_id IS NOT NULL)`

... and I get back a couple thousand rows.  My question is: Why did the first query seem to operate on the idea that any number = NULL? Or is this an odd effect that NULL has on the `IN()` statement? I feel like this is something basic that I've missed. I don't usually use NULL in my db tables at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is why `NOT EXISTS` is semantically correct

```
SELECT * FROM artists ar
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT * FROM albums al WHERE ar.artist_id = al.artist_id)
```

Logic:

- `NOT IN (x, y, NULL)` is actually

  - `NOT (x OR y OR NULL)` is actually

    - `(NOT x) AND (NOT y) AND (NOT NULL)`

So `NULL` invalidates the whole `NOT IN`

Comment: Seems like NOT EXISTS was marginally quicker, too. Thanks a lot for the info!

Answer (score 7):

Quick answer - the `IN` statement is a shortcut for `=a OR =b OR ...`. If you include nulls in this list, then I think that is breaking the statement. Your second option is probably a better option.

Or using a join might also work, and be more efficient.

Comment: true OR unknown evaluates to true. And it's a NOT IN: which breaks down differently

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the way SQL NULL's are interpreted - You have to think of them as UNKNOWN value.

Lets say you have artist_id = 1

If you run the following:

```
artist_id = NULL
```

Rather than getting a 'False' - you get 'UNKNOWN';

When you run a query such as yours, only values evaluating to 'TRUE' are returned.

```
artist_id IN (NULL, NULL, NULL...) = UNKNOWN
artist_id NOT IN (NULL, NULL, NULL....) = UNKNOWN
```

Comment: Fair enough, though I would then retort - why use null at all? Were this my database design, I would have used 0 in place of null when there isn't an artist. Any compelling reason why one should use null instead?

Comment: Its definitely debatable. I personally use them as convenient placeholders - if I'm loading a table that frequently has many unknown fields, rather than always having to set the blank values (i.e. '', n/a, etc), I just consistently stick with NULL. I'm happy with this method - though some would consider this bad practice.

Comment: @Chris, some people argue that using placeholder values is more confusing, since anyone viewing the data must know which value is the placeholder.  It cannot be a universal solution because there will always be designs in which no reasonable placeholder value can be chosen.  There are also practical benefits to using NULL -- it requires less storage both in tables and indexes, and therefore can also increase performance.

Comment: @Dave Costa - +1, thanks for the explanation (and validation).

Comment: Is the performance value gained in smaller index space mitigated by the need to use specialized operators such as IS NOT NULL as opposed to a direct `=` comparison? Seems like the former is a "function call" whereas the latter is a simple comparison. I personally don't find 0 to be a confusing placeholder at all! :)